# How to make button open another fragment from within another fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

how to make button to open another fragment. being within a fragment. kotlin

I'm starting in kotlin and I'm having a hard time trying to open a fragment with a button, how do I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction to add your fragment on the fly. you can call a function similar to this in your button's onClick method. But it is recommended for the parent activity to handle each fragment's lifecycle and the fragments 
are not supposed to interact each other. The following is taken from the developer docs, [that can be found here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating).
"Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done either through a shared ViewModel or through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly."

```
fun createFragmentonTheFly(){
        var mFragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        mFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fr_container,new ProductListFragment()) 
        mFragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
```

The best way to do it would be to add an interface let say onFragmentDetachedLisetner and add one method replaceFragment() or something and make your Activity implement this interaface and had it replace as soon as the fragment is detached and make your fragment that contains your button finish itself when user clicks the button, then your activity will replace it with the one you wanted to start. And also consider reusing fragments, as that is the main purpose of fragments at the first place.